# How to make active/passive jboss resource in pacemaker

Tags: high-availability, failover, jboss, pacemaker, corosync

I want to configure my pacemaker for jboss server. I have 2 nodes with mysql master/slave configured. The problem is I want to start jboss on node which is located master database. The one possible solution for this: Start jboss on 2 nodes, but deploy application only in one node where master is located. How can I solve this?

My current configuration is:

```
node oxygen \
        attributes standby="off" p_mysql_mysql_master_IP="10.3.1.4"
node oxygen2 \
        attributes standby="off" p_mysql_mysql_master_IP="10.3.1.5"
primitive VIRT_IP ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 \
        params ip="192.168.1.250" nic="eth1" \
        meta target-role="Started"
primitive p_mysql ocf:percona:mysql \
        params config="/etc/mysql/my.cnf" pid="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid" socket="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock" replication_user="repl_user" replication_passwd="ola5P1ZMU" max_slave_lag="60" evict_outdated_slaves="false" binary="/usr/bin/mysqld_safe" test_user="test_user" test_passwd="2JcXCxKF" \
        op monitor interval="5s" role="Master" OCF_CHECK_LEVEL="1" \
        op monitor interval="2s" role="Slave" OCF_CHECK_LEVEL="1" \
        op start interval="0" timeout="60s" \
        op stop interval="0" timeout="60s"
ms ms_MySQL p_mysql \
        meta master-max="1" master-node-max="1" clone-max="2" clone-node-max="1" notify="true" globally-unique="false" target-role="Started" is-managed="true"
property $id="cib-bootstrap-options" \
        dc-version="1.1.7-ee0730e13d124c3d58f00016c3376a1de5323cff" \
        cluster-infrastructure="openais" \
        expected-quorum-votes="2" \
        stonith-enabled="false" \
        no-quorum-policy="ignore" \
        stop-all-resources="false" \
        maintenance-mode="false"
property $id="mysql_replication" \
        p_mysql_REPL_INFO="10.3.1.4|mysql-bin.000030|107"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have do similar configuration to make sure the virtual IP to live along with Mysql master server. For your case, I think the steps should be:

- Add a primitive for two JBOSS intances (as your shareIP or MySQL servers)
- Add colocation configure for JBOSS primitive to live along with MySQL Master as example below:
  colocation mysql_co_jboss inf: jboss ms_MySQL:Master